# How to dynamically load WordPress custom post type data with jQuery on click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I will try to explain what I am trying to do here. I have created a custom post named "People" and created some new posts.

Now, I have created a modal with JS with static content which works.

But instead of loading all the posts from the custom post type when the page is loaded, I want to only show the modal data on click for each specific ID. Instead of having 10 or 20 same modal output HTML when loaded.

So on click.. I want to show the data of this specific CP post.

Modal People feed HTML (each figure opens a modal):

```
<section class="feed">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row content">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <div class="feed__inner">
                <figure data-post-id="1" class="feed__item">
                    <img class="feed__image" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1845534/pexels-photo-1845534.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" />
                </figure>

                <figure data-post-id="2" class="feed__item">
                    <img class="feed__image" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/614810/pexels-photo-614810.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" />
                </figure>

                <figure data-post-id="3" class="feed__item">
                    <img class="feed__image" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2613260/pexels-photo-2613260.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" />
                </figure>

                <figure data-post-id="4" class="feed__item">
                    <img class="feed__image" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2379004/pexels-photo-2379004.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" />
                </figure>

                <figure data-post-id="5" class="feed__item">
                    <img class="feed__image" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1782286/pexels-photo-1782286.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" />
                </figure>

                <figure data-post-id="6" class="feed__item">
                    <img class="feed__image" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1858175/pexels-photo-1858175.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" />
                </figure>

                <figure data-post-id="7" class="feed__item">
                    <img class="feed__image" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1468379/pexels-photo-1468379.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" />
                </figure>

                <figure data-post-id="8" class="feed__item">
                    <img class="feed__image" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2590709/pexels-photo-2590709.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" />
                </figure>

                <figure data-post-id="9" class="feed__item">
                    <img class="feed__image" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/247206/pexels-photo-247206.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" />
                </figure>

                <figure data-post-id="10" class="feed__item">
                    <img class="feed__image" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1599980/pexels-photo-1599980.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" />
                </figure>

                <figure data-post-id="11" class="feed__item">
                    <img class="feed__image" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1172784/pexels-photo-1172784.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" />
                </figure>

                <figure data-post-id="12" class="feed__item">
                    <img class="feed__image" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1624229/pexels-photo-1624229.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" />
                </figure>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<?php require THEME_DIR_COMPONENTS . '/modal.php'; ?>
```

My Modal HTML:

```
<section class="modal">
        <div class="modal__inner">
        <div class="modal__bg"></div>
        <span class="btn btn__close btn__close--primary btn__close--large btn__close--top-right btn__close--highlighted"></span>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row modal__wrapper modal__wrapper--large modal__wrapper--dark">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <div class="modal__image">
                            <img draggable="false" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2613260/pexels-photo-2613260.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Test">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <div class="modal__content">
                            <div class="modal__content--top">
                                <h1 class="modal__title">Chantall <span>Dans</span></h1>
                                <span class="modal__date">15.9.2019</span>
                                <span class="modal__category">Muziek</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal__content--bottom">
                                <div class="modal__description">
                                    <p class="modal__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
                                    <a href="#instagram" class="modal__url modal__url--secondary" target="_blank">
                                        <span class="icon icon__instagram"></span>
                                        Chantall95
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal__content--bottom">
                            <h4 class="modal__subtitle">Tags</h4>
                                <div class="modal__description">
                                    <ul class="tag__list">
                                        <li class="tag__item tag__item--primary">Modern</li>
                                        <li class="tag__item tag__item--primary">Breakdance</li>
                                        <li class="tag__item tag__item--primary">Freestyle</li>
                                        <li class="tag__item tag__item--primary">urban</li>
                                        <li class="tag__item tag__item--primary">Pop</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

How can I load modal data only if requested/on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with AJAX.

Create  `single-people.php` file that outputs the post as you like and either request it via ajax on popup open.

e.g.(assumes jquery)

```
<script>
    function openPopup(id)
    {
        fetch('http://example.com?p='+id).then(
         function(response){
            $('#popup-content').html(response.body);
            $('.popup').show();
         });
    }
</script>

<button onclick="openPopup(1)">Open popup #1</button>
<button onclick="openPopup(2)">Open popup #2</button>

<div class="popup">
<div id="popup-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I fetch post type posts?

Comment: You fetch a page single-people.php that renders items from your custom post type.

Comment: You are right since there is a post type "people" using single-people.php will fetch the correct data. Thanks will give this a try.